# On clicking tabs update the url and Navigate on clicking Browser Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple Tab. On clicking the Tab Head I want the URL to get updated like:

```
http:/somepath/demo-tabs/#tab2 or http:/somepath/demo-tabs/#tab3
```

As well as I want these tabs to be navigated as and when I clicked the Prev and Next button of the Browser. Which also seems to be working fine. But the point is the page jumps every time the Tabs are clicked. How can I stop page Jump with all the other things still working. i.e URL gets updated and it works on clicking the browsers Prev and Next buttons.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
 $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").click();
});
```

Above is the code I used, which I got from my previous post question. This makes my tab working on clicking the Prev and Next buttons of the browser. Below is the HTML sample markup for tab and Jquery:

```
ul>
  <li><a href="#content1">Head 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#content2">Head 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content"> Some Content/........</div>
<div class="content"> Some Content/........</div> 

$(document).ready(function() {
var tabHead = $('ul li');
var tabContent = $('.content');

tabContent.not(':first').hide().end();
  tabHead.on('click',function() { 
    tabContent.hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
  });
});
```

I found `window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”); on research. However could you help me with the sources or links or demo on how to actualy use it.

And I don't want to use AJAX. Just simple Jquery or JS.